Vega-Lite 5.30.0 - retaining null values for proper conditional formatting
I have a Vega-Lite map, and I'm confused by Vega-Lite's behavior coloring areas with a conditional statement. Some input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Goals: In my data, some of the neighborhoods' values are suppressed; I'm trying to display these suppressed values as gray (#808080 in the spec) and keep the tooltip the same as on the non-suppressed neighborhoods. For the map's color encoding, I have a condition, testing for isValid(datum.Value), and if that's true, applying the color scale, and if it's false, applying #808080.
Question: In Vega 5.30.0, one change from 5.29.0 makes vega format null as "null." As a result, my conditional statement that tests for null data and styles accordingly doesn't work - instead of treating these as nulls, it treats these as 0 values. Using Vega 5.30.0, how can I keep null data as null, so that conditionals checking for it can accurately find and style null data how I want to?
Further background: a spec is here - one of the neighborhoods to be suppressed is the northern neighborhood on the south-western island ("Northern SI"). For invalid data (where datum.Value == null), it's not applying #808080, the value in the else part of the statement - it's just treating those nulls as 0s and applying the lowest part of the color scale in the test part of the condition. I've tried "test": "isValid(datum.Value)" (isValid should return true if value is not null, undefined, or NaN, and false otherwise), but it colors neighborhoods where Value == null. The same goes for "test": "datum.Value != null".
I've tried a handful of other things, too (including adding a separate true/false Suppressed field), but each approach seems to involve Vega-Lite treating nulls like 0s, or struggling with a conditional test involving null data. While experimenting, if I reverse the logic (eg with "test": "datum.Suppressed == true"), the 'else' works as expected but styles for satisfying the test condition do not.
(Curiously - though this may be a separate issue - when I use "test": "isValid(datum.DisplayValue" it colors neighborhoods where datum.DisplayValue is alphanumeric; there's something happening that I do not understand.)
Input is greatly appreciated here! Again, thanks in advance.
Edit: updating with complete spec.
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "title": {
    "text": "Adults with asthma (past 12 months)",
    "subtitlePadding": 10,
    "fontWeight": "normal",
    "anchor": "start",
    "fontSize": 18,
    "font": "sans-serif",
    "baseline": "top",
    "subtitle": "Percent",
    "subtitleFontSize": 13
  },
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 101,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 7.8,
        "CI": "(3.0, 18.8)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "7.8*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Kingsbridge - Riverdale",
        "Lat": 40.8926,
        "Long": -73.9012,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 102,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 4.1,
        "CI": "(1.7, 9.4)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "4.1*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Northeast Bronx",
        "Lat": 40.8806,
        "Long": -73.8448,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 103,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 6.8,
        "CI": "(4.3, 10.5)",
        "Note": "",
        "DisplayValue": "6.8",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Fordham - Bronx Pk",
        "Lat": 40.8721,
        "Long": -73.8807,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 104,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 7.7,
        "CI": "(4.9, 11.7)",
        "Note": "",
        "DisplayValue": "7.7",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Pelham - Throgs Neck",
        "Lat": 40.8405,
        "Long": -73.8338,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 201,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 1.3,
        "CI": "(0.4, 4.1)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "1.3*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Greenpoint",
        "Lat": 40.7202,
        "Long": -73.9497,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 202,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 3.8,
        "CI": "(1.8, 7.7)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "3.8*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Downtown - Heights - Slope",
        "Lat": 40.6836,
        "Long": -73.9864,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 203,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 4.3,
        "CI": "(2.6, 6.9)",
        "Note": "",
        "DisplayValue": "4.3",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Bedford Stuyvesant - Crown Heights",
        "Lat": 40.6735,
        "Long": -73.9334,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 204,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 6.9,
        "CI": "(2.8, 15.9)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "6.9*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "East New York",
        "Lat": 40.6721,
        "Long": -73.883,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 205,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": null,
        "CI": "",
        "Note": "** Estimate is suppressed due to insufficient data.",
        "DisplayValue": "**",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Sunset Park",
        "Lat": 40.6477,
        "Long": -74.0091,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 206,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 2,
        "CI": "(0.8, 4.9)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "2.0*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Borough Park",
        "Lat": 40.6284,
        "Long": -73.9804,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 207,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 5.2,
        "CI": "(2.5, 10.6)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "5.2*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "East Flatbush - Flatbush",
        "Lat": 40.6464,
        "Long": -73.9484,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 208,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 4.8,
        "CI": "(2.2, 10.1)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "4.8*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Canarsie - Flatlands",
        "Lat": 40.6203,
        "Long": -73.9037,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 209,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 3.5,
        "CI": "(1.7, 7.3)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "3.5*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Bensonhurst - Bay Ridge",
        "Lat": 40.6118,
        "Long": -74.0126,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 210,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 2.8,
        "CI": "(1.1, 7.5)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "2.8*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Coney Island - Sheepshead Bay",
        "Lat": 40.5904,
        "Long": -73.9612,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 211,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 8.8,
        "CI": "(4.7, 15.8)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "8.8*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Williamsburg - Bushwick",
        "Lat": 40.6986,
        "Long": -73.9316,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 301,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 5.8,
        "CI": "(2.4, 13.4)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "5.8*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Washington Heights",
        "Lat": 40.8495,
        "Long": -73.9351,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 302,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": null,
        "CI": "",
        "Note": "** Estimate is suppressed due to insufficient data.",
        "DisplayValue": "**",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Central Harlem - Morningside Heights",
        "Lat": 40.8132,
        "Long": -73.9484,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 303,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 3.9,
        "CI": "(1.5, 9.8)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "3.9*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "East Harlem",
        "Lat": 40.794,
        "Long": -73.935,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 304,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 7.9,
        "CI": "(2.9, 19.6)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "7.9*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Upper West Side",
        "Lat": 40.7884,
        "Long": -73.9756,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 401,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": null,
        "CI": "",
        "Note": "** Estimate is suppressed due to insufficient data.",
        "DisplayValue": "**",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Long Island City - Astoria",
        "Lat": 40.7575,
        "Long": -73.9278,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 402,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 3.1,
        "CI": "(1.6, 6.0)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "3.1*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "West Queens",
        "Lat": 40.7441,
        "Long": -73.8879,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 403,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 1.7,
        "CI": "(0.8, 3.7)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "1.7*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Flushing - Clearview",
        "Lat": 40.7707,
        "Long": -73.8151,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 405,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 2,
        "CI": "(0.7, 5.7)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "2.0*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Ridgewood - Forest Hills",
        "Lat": 40.7112,
        "Long": -73.8723,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 407,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 4,
        "CI": "(2.1, 7.7)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "4.0*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Southwest Queens",
        "Lat": 40.6795,
        "Long": -73.8355,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 408,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 4.7,
        "CI": "(2.3, 9.3)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "4.7*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Jamaica",
        "Lat": 40.696,
        "Long": -73.7831,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 409,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": null,
        "CI": "",
        "Note": "** Estimate is suppressed due to insufficient data.",
        "DisplayValue": "**",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Southeast Queens",
        "Lat": 40.7022,
        "Long": -73.7371,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 410,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 3.9,
        "CI": "(1.8, 8.3)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "3.9*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Rockaways",
        "Lat": 40.59,
        "Long": -73.8228,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 305307,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 3.6,
        "CI": "(2.0, 6.4)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "3.6*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Upper East Side-Gramercy",
        "Lat": 40.7609,
        "Long": -73.9648,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 306308,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 1.9,
        "CI": "(0.8, 4.4)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "1.9*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Chelsea-Village  ",
        "Lat": 40.7448,
        "Long": -73.9972,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 309310,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 4.3,
        "CI": "(2.1, 8.6)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "4.3*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Union Square-Lower Manhattan",
        "Lat": 40.7164,
        "Long": -73.9948,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 404406,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": null,
        "CI": "",
        "Note": "** Estimate is suppressed due to insufficient data.",
        "DisplayValue": "**",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Bayside Little Neck-Fresh Meadows",
        "Lat": 40.7471,
        "Long": -73.7763,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 501502,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": null,
        "CI": "",
        "Note": "** Estimate is suppressed due to insufficient data.",
        "DisplayValue": "**",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Northern SI",
        "Lat": 40.6178,
        "Long": -74.1076,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 503504,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 3.3,
        "CI": "(1.5, 7.2)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "3.3*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Southern SI",
        "Lat": 40.5652,
        "Long": -74.1727,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 105106107,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 6.3,
        "CI": "(4.4, 8.9)",
        "Note": "",
        "DisplayValue": "6.3",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "South Bronx",
        "Lat": 40.8274,
        "Long": -73.9018,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      }
    ],
    "format": {"parse": {"Value": "number"}}
  },
  "config": {
    "concat": {"spacing": 20},
    "view": {"stroke": "transparent"},
    "axisY": {"domain": false, "ticks": false},
    "legend": {"disable": true}
  },
  "projection": {"type": "mercator"},
  "transform": [{"calculate": "datum.DisplayValue + ' %'", "as": "valueLabel"}],
  "vconcat": [
    {
      "layer": [
        {
          "height": 500,
          "width": "container",
          "data": {
            "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nychealth/EHDP-data/production/geography/borough.topo.json",
            "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "collection"}
          },
          "mark": {
            "type": "geoshape",
            "stroke": "#fafafa",
            "fill": "#C5C5C5",
            "strokeWidth": 0.5
          }
        },
        {
          "height": 500,
          "width": "container",
          "data": {
            "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nychealth/EHDP-data/production/geography/UHF34.topo.json",
            "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "collection"}
          },
          "mark": {
            "type": "geoshape",
            "stroke": "#a2a2a2",
            "fill": "#e7e7e7",
            "strokeWidth": 0.5
          }
        },
        {
          "height": 500,
          "width": "container",
          "mark": {"type": "geoshape", "invalid": null},
          "params": [
            {
              "name": "highlight",
              "select": {
                "type": "point",
                "on": "mouseover",
                "clear": "mouseout"
              }
            }
          ],
          "transform": [
            {
              "lookup": "GeoID",
              "from": {
                "data": {
                  "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nychealth/EHDP-data/production/geography/UHF34.topo.json",
                  "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "collection"}
                },
                "key": "properties.GEOCODE"
              },
              "as": "geo"
            }
          ],
          "encoding": {
            "shape": {"field": "geo", "type": "geojson"},
            "color": {
              "condition": {
                "test": "isValid(datum.Value)",
                "bin": false,
                "field": "Value",
                "type": "quantitative",
                "scale": {"scheme": {"name": "reds", "extent": [0.125, 1.25]}},
                "legend": {
                  "direction": "horizontal",
                  "orient": "top-left",
                  "title": null,
                  "tickCount": 3,
                  "offset": -25,
                  "gradientLength": 200
                }
              },
              "value": "#808080"
            },
            "stroke": {
              "condition": [
                {"param": "highlight", "empty": false, "value": "cyan"}
              ],
              "value": "#2d2d2d"
            },
            "strokeWidth": {
              "condition": [
                {"param": "highlight", "empty": false, "value": 1.25}
              ],
              "value": 0.5
            },
            "order": {
              "condition": [{"param": "highlight", "empty": false, "value": 1}],
              "value": 0
            },
            "tooltip": [
              {"field": "Geography", "title": "Neighborhood"},
              {"field": "valueLabel", "title": "Percent"},
              {"field": "TimePeriod", "title": "Time period"}
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "height": 150,
      "width": "container",
      "config": {"axisY": {"labelAngle": 0, "labelFontSize": 13}},
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "tooltip": true, "stroke": "#161616"},
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "highlight",
          "select": {"type": "point", "on": "mouseover", "clear": "mouseout"}
        }
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "Value",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "title": null,
          "axis": {"labelAngle": 0, "labelFontSize": 11, "tickCount": 3}
        },
        "tooltip": [
          {"field": "Geography", "title": "Neighborhood"},
          {"field": "valueLabel", "title": "Percent"},
          {"field": "TimePeriod", "title": "Time period"}
        ],
        "x": {"field": "GeoID", "sort": "y", "axis": null},
        "color": {
          "bin": false,
          "field": "Value",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "scale": {"scheme": {"name": "reds", "extent": [0.125, 1.25]}},
          "legend": false
        },
        "stroke": {
          "condition": [
            {"param": "highlight", "empty": false, "value": "cyan"}
          ],
          "value": "white"
        },
        "strokeWidth": {
          "condition": [{"param": "highlight", "empty": false, "value": 3}],
          "value": 0
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}


Update 2:
This also seems fine and doesn't need the hidden point.
 "color": {
              "condition": {
                "test": "datum.Value != null",
                "field": "Value",
                "scale": {"scheme": {"name": "reds", "extent": [0.125, 1.25]}}
              },
              "value": "#808080"
            },

Update:

{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "title": {
    "text": "Adults with asthma (past 12 months)",
    "subtitlePadding": 10,
    "fontWeight": "normal",
    "anchor": "start",
    "fontSize": 18,
    "font": "sans-serif",
    "baseline": "top",
    "subtitle": "Percent",
    "subtitleFontSize": 13
  },
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 101,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 7.8,
        "Suppressed": false,
        "CI": "(3.0, 18.8)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "7.8*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Kingsbridge - Riverdale",
        "Lat": 40.8926,
        "Long": -73.9012,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 102,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 4.1,
        "Suppressed": false,
        "CI": "(1.7, 9.4)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "4.1*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Northeast Bronx",
        "Lat": 40.8806,
        "Long": -73.8448,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 103,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 6.8,
        "Suppressed": false,
        "CI": "(4.3, 10.5)",
        "Note": "",
        "DisplayValue": "6.8",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Fordham - Bronx Pk",
        "Lat": 40.8721,
        "Long": -73.8807,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 104,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 7.7,
        "Suppressed": false,
        "CI": "(4.9, 11.7)",
        "Note": "",
        "DisplayValue": "7.7",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Pelham - Throgs Neck",
        "Lat": 40.8405,
        "Long": -73.8338,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 201,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 1.3,
        "Suppressed": false,
        "CI": "(0.4, 4.1)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "1.3*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Greenpoint",
        "Lat": 40.7202,
        "Long": -73.9497,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 202,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 3.8,
        "Suppressed": false,
        "CI": "(1.8, 7.7)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "3.8*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Downtown - Heights - Slope",
        "Lat": 40.6836,
        "Long": -73.9864,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 203,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 4.3,
        "Suppressed": false,
        "CI": "(2.6, 6.9)",
        "Note": "",
        "DisplayValue": "4.3",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Bedford Stuyvesant - Crown Heights",
        "Lat": 40.6735,
        "Long": -73.9334,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 204,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 6.9,
        "Suppressed": false,
        "CI": "(2.8, 15.9)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "6.9*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "East New York",
        "Lat": 40.6721,
        "Long": -73.883,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 205,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": null,
        "Suppressed": true,
        "CI": "",
        "Note": "** Estimate is suppressed due to insufficient data.",
        "DisplayValue": "**",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Sunset Park",
        "Lat": 40.6477,
        "Long": -74.0091,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 206,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 2,
        "Suppressed": false,
        "CI": "(0.8, 4.9)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "2.0*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Borough Park",
        "Lat": 40.6284,
        "Long": -73.9804,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 207,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 5.2,
        "Suppressed": false,
        "CI": "(2.5, 10.6)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "5.2*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "East Flatbush - Flatbush",
        "Lat": 40.6464,
        "Long": -73.9484,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 208,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 4.8,
        "Suppressed": false,
        "CI": "(2.2, 10.1)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "4.8*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Canarsie - Flatlands",
        "Lat": 40.6203,
        "Long": -73.9037,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 209,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 3.5,
        "Suppressed": false,
        "CI": "(1.7, 7.3)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "3.5*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Bensonhurst - Bay Ridge",
        "Lat": 40.6118,
        "Long": -74.0126,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 210,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 2.8,
        "Suppressed": false,
        "CI": "(1.1, 7.5)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "2.8*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Coney Island - Sheepshead Bay",
        "Lat": 40.5904,
        "Long": -73.9612,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 211,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 8.8,
        "Suppressed": false,
        "CI": "(4.7, 15.8)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "8.8*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Williamsburg - Bushwick",
        "Lat": 40.6986,
        "Long": -73.9316,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 301,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 5.8,
        "Suppressed": false,
        "CI": "(2.4, 13.4)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "5.8*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Washington Heights",
        "Lat": 40.8495,
        "Long": -73.9351,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 302,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": null,
        "Suppressed": true,
        "CI": "",
        "Note": "** Estimate is suppressed due to insufficient data.",
        "DisplayValue": "**",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Central Harlem - Morningside Heights",
        "Lat": 40.8132,
        "Long": -73.9484,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 303,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 3.9,
        "Suppressed": false,
        "CI": "(1.5, 9.8)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "3.9*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "East Harlem",
        "Lat": 40.794,
        "Long": -73.935,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 304,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 7.9,
        "Suppressed": false,
        "CI": "(2.9, 19.6)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "7.9*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Upper West Side",
        "Lat": 40.7884,
        "Long": -73.9756,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 401,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": null,
        "Suppressed": true,
        "CI": "",
        "Note": "** Estimate is suppressed due to insufficient data.",
        "DisplayValue": "**",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Long Island City - Astoria",
        "Lat": 40.7575,
        "Long": -73.9278,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 402,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 3.1,
        "Suppressed": false,
        "CI": "(1.6, 6.0)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "3.1*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "West Queens",
        "Lat": 40.7441,
        "Long": -73.8879,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 403,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 1.7,
        "Suppressed": false,
        "CI": "(0.8, 3.7)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "1.7*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Flushing - Clearview",
        "Lat": 40.7707,
        "Long": -73.8151,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 405,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 2,
        "Suppressed": false,
        "CI": "(0.7, 5.7)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "2.0*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Ridgewood - Forest Hills",
        "Lat": 40.7112,
        "Long": -73.8723,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 407,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 4,
        "Suppressed": false,
        "CI": "(2.1, 7.7)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "4.0*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Southwest Queens",
        "Lat": 40.6795,
        "Long": -73.8355,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 408,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 4.7,
        "Suppressed": false,
        "CI": "(2.3, 9.3)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "4.7*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Jamaica",
        "Lat": 40.696,
        "Long": -73.7831,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 409,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": null,
        "Suppressed": true,
        "CI": "",
        "Note": "** Estimate is suppressed due to insufficient data.",
        "DisplayValue": "**",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Southeast Queens",
        "Lat": 40.7022,
        "Long": -73.7371,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 410,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 3.9,
        "Suppressed": false,
        "CI": "(1.8, 8.3)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "3.9*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Rockaways",
        "Lat": 40.59,
        "Long": -73.8228,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 305307,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 3.6,
        "Suppressed": false,
        "CI": "(2.0, 6.4)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "3.6*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Upper East Side-Gramercy",
        "Lat": 40.7609,
        "Long": -73.9648,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 306308,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 1.9,
        "Suppressed": false,
        "CI": "(0.8, 4.4)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "1.9*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Chelsea-Village  ",
        "Lat": 40.7448,
        "Long": -73.9972,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 309310,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 4.3,
        "Suppressed": false,
        "CI": "(2.1, 8.6)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "4.3*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Union Square-Lower Manhattan",
        "Lat": 40.7164,
        "Long": -73.9948,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 404406,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": null,
        "Suppressed": true,
        "CI": "",
        "Note": "** Estimate is suppressed due to insufficient data.",
        "DisplayValue": "**",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Bayside Little Neck-Fresh Meadows",
        "Lat": 40.7471,
        "Long": -73.7763,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 501502,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": null,
        "Suppressed": true,
        "CI": "",
        "Note": "** Estimate is suppressed due to insufficient data.",
        "DisplayValue": "**",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Northern SI",
        "Lat": 40.6178,
        "Long": -74.1076,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 503504,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 3.3,
        "Suppressed": false,
        "CI": "(1.5, 7.2)",
        "Note": "* Estimate is based on small numbers so should be interpreted with caution.",
        "DisplayValue": "3.3*",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "Southern SI",
        "Lat": 40.5652,
        "Long": -74.1727,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      },
      {
        "MeasureID": 363,
        "GeoID": 105106107,
        "GeoType": "UHF34",
        "TimePeriodID": 296,
        "Value": 6.3,
        "Suppressed": false,
        "CI": "(4.4, 8.9)",
        "Note": "",
        "DisplayValue": "6.3",
        "GeoRank": 3,
        "GeoTypeDesc": "UHF 34",
        "GeoTypeShortDesc": "Neighborhood (UHF 34)",
        "Geography": "South Bronx",
        "Lat": 40.8274,
        "Long": -73.9018,
        "TimePeriod": "2022",
        "start_period": 1640995200000,
        "end_period": 1672444800000
      }
    ],
    "format": {"parse": {"Value": "number"}}
  },
  "config": {
    "concat": {"spacing": 20},
    "view": {"stroke": "transparent"},
    "axisY": {"domain": false, "ticks": false},
    "legend": {"disable": true}
  },
  "projection": {"type": "mercator"},
  "transform": [{"calculate": "datum.DisplayValue + ' %'", "as": "valueLabel"}],
  "vconcat": [
    {
      "layer": [
        {
          "height": 500,
          "width": "container",
          "data": {
            "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nychealth/EHDP-data/production/geography/borough.topo.json",
            "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "collection"}
          },
          "mark": {
            "type": "geoshape",
            "stroke": "#fafafa",
            "fill": "#f2f2f2",
            "strokeWidth": 0.5
          }
        },
        {
          "height": 1,
          "width": 1,
          "mark": {"type": "point"},
          "encoding": {
            "color": {
              "field": "Value",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"scheme": {"name": "reds", "extent": [0.125, 1.25]}}
            }, "opacity":{"value":0}
          }
        },
        {
          "height": 500,
          "width": "container",
          "mark": {"type": "geoshape", "invalid": null},
          "params": [
            {
              "name": "highlight",
              "select": {
                "type": "point",
                "on": "mouseover",
                "clear": "mouseout"
              }
            }
          ],
          "transform": [
            {
              "lookup": "GeoID",
              "from": {
                "data": {
                  "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nychealth/EHDP-data/production/geography/UHF34.topo.json",
                  "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "collection"}
                },
                "key": "properties.GEOCODE"
              },
              "as": "geo"
            }
          ],
          "encoding": {
            "shape": {"field": "geo", "type": "geojson"},
            "fill": {"value":{"expr":"datum.Value ==null?'#808080':scale('color', datum.Value)"}},
            "stroke": {
              "condition": [
                {"param": "highlight", "empty": false, "value": "cyan"}
              ],
              "value": "#2d2d2d"
            },
            "strokeWidth": {
              "condition": [
                {"param": "highlight", "empty": false, "value": 1.25}
              ],
              "value": 0.5
            },
            "order": {
              "condition": [{"param": "highlight", "empty": false, "value": 1}],
              "value": 0
            },
            "tooltip": [
              {"field": "Geography", "title": "Neighborhood"},
              {"field": "valueLabel", "title": "Percent"},
              {"field": "TimePeriod", "title": "Time period"}
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


Thanks, but that's demonstrating the problem I'm running into - it's not applying "value": "#808080" to the null data. The gray that appears is just from first layer.

I see the problem. I have updated now with a hidden point mark to generate a scale you can reuse.

Did this work in 5.29? If so, you might want to raise an issue on GitHub so the devs are aware of a regression

Thanks. Unfortunately I simplified the spec a little to remove some noise for the purpose of focusing this question, and as a result, when I apply this fix to my full spec I get a bunch of legend issues. I appreciate you looking in to this; I'm going to take a beat to wrap my head around the issue and will likely post again.

I posted a second update. Try that one.

I did, thanks; just updated the post with the complete spec - you'll notice that some funny legend stuff happens!

I would just go the Vega route and then you can control everything. Transpile the code to Vega and remove the offending line and it works. Ask a new question if you need help.
